# Find top k tag at any point in time, from a stream of tags

Tags: java, priority-queue, min-heap

I need to find the top k tags from a stream of tags, at any point in time during the flow.

I am able to find the top K tags at the end of the flow, by using HashMap and PriorityQueue of size K. But, i am not sure on how to modify this approach to find top tags during the stream of tags, i.e if the tag is already among top ten and just update it's count, instead of adding the same tag again with the new count.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you're asking. The simplest is to just re-compute the top K tags every time you're asked. That is, you maintain a histogram of some kind, and when somebody asks for the top K, you run through the algorithm that uses a priority queue to figure out the top K items. This has the benefit of simplicity, but it takes time.

You could maintain that list of the top K if you like, and whenever some other item is updated you check to see if its new count is higher than the count for the smallest item in the top K. If it is, then replace that smallest item with the newly updated item. That should be easy enough to do with an auxiliary data structure. The primary drawback here is the memory it takes to keep a copy of the top K items.

Another way to do it would be to keep your hash map with counts, and an additional linked list that orders things by descending count. The data in the hash table contains references to the linked list nodes. Whenever an item is updated, you update its count and then compare its count with the count of the item just before it in the linked list. If the new count is greater than the count of the item's predecessor, move the item up in the list to keep it in order. Of course, you might have to move it multiple times. This is essentially an insertion sort.

The benefit of that approach is that the top K items are always at the front of the list. The drawback is potentially performance. If you have a lot of items and your range of counts is small, each update can cost O(n) time. You can speed that up some by keeping track of the next higher item so that, for example, if there are 100 items with a count of 1, you have a reference to the last item with a count of 2. So when you increase the count of an item with count 1, you don't have to sift it up through all of the items with count 1. This costs you more memory (in the worst case, O(n) memory), but it makes insertion O(1), and keeps the list in order.

There are other possibilities, all of which make tradeoffs between speed and memory usage. Which you choose depends on how much memory you want to spend and how fast you want this thing to be.